# serialport exception java

Tags: java, exception, serial-port

I'm reading data from serial port using `javax.comm` API but when I run the code 2-3 times it is showing port currently own by this,but I have closed the port. What's the problem here? I'm not getting it, please help me.

This is expectation:

> javax.comm.PortInUseException: Port currently owned by flashhandler.TwoWaySerialComm

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the port, then try enabling it again. Also try to check if the process using it terminated successfully. Hope this helps.